# How to know if a charger will be compatible with Lenovo T15?

Tags: laptop, battery, power, usb-c

I don't have my charger for Lenovo T15 Gen 1. I bought a temporary replacement until I get it back.

But, with the replacement, I get a message on startup that the charger has insufficient wattage and the laptop does not charge at all.

The charger I bought is Vention FEG, claims to be 100W charger. It says that it supports these protocols:

OC3, SCP, FCP, AFC, PE 2 and SFCP.

It says on the box that this is a GaN charger.

I am not sure why it does not work. Is this something specific to the laptop, or did I use a wrong charger? How, in general, do I ensure that the charger I buy can negotiate the correct voltage and current with the laptop?

Comment: The original charger supported 65 Watts, so a 100 Watt charger, should be more then adequate. Which suggests that the 100 Watt charger does not reach the same wattage with the same amperage and voltage.  So what are the specifications of this Vention FEG, charger? I am hoping you are not trying to charge your laptop with a GaN Charger.

Comment: It says GaN charger on the box. Why is that wrong? One other thing I now see is that the USB-A port on the charger is only rated at 30W, but also has two USB-C sockets one if which is rated at 90W.

Comment: I would never expect a GaN charger to charge a Lenovo laptop. Lenovo T15 Gen 1 or Gen 2?

Comment: Gen 1. I tried to look any info on GaN chargers and laptops but all I am getting are ads and reviews. Feel free to post an answer explaining why it was wrong. It might not solve my problem, but at least could help someone in the future.

Comment: Lenovo  sales [one GaN charger](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/chargers-and-batteries/chargers/40awgc65ww).

Comment: The [tech specs](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_T15_Gen_1/ThinkPad_T15_Gen_1_Spec.PDF) states that the Lenovo T15 supports PD (Power Delivery) 3.0 at 45W or 65W. The power adapter doesn’t support PD 3.0; it only supports OC3, SCP, FCP, AFC, PE 2 and SFCP.

Answer (score 1):

Please review this article.

[Lenov forum on GAN adapter](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/Does-T15p-Gen-3-support-USB-C-charging-at-100W/m-p/5230375)

Welcome to Lenovo Community UtsavAtStat,

> According to the official Lenovo ThinkPad T15p Gen 3 specification
> sheet
> (https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_T15p_Gen_3/ThinkPad_T15p_Gen_3_Spec.pdf),
> the laptop does not support USB-C charging at 100W. Therefore, if you
> need to charge your ThinkPad T15p Gen 3 while on your work trip, you
> will need to bring the slim tip charger that came with the laptop.
>
> Regards,
>
> Hassen_Lenovo

So the simplest answer here is that your T15 does not support the adapter you purchased and you need the proper Lenovo AC adapter.

How do you know if a charger will be compatible with a Lenovo Laptop?  If Lenovo does not say it is supported, you can reasonably assume it is not supported

I am a long time Lenovo user and always use a Lenovo charger and keep a spare.